# how do I view database from "Azure database for MySQL server"

Tags: mysql, azure

I'm currently trying azure and imported Database from MySQL, I see my Database online and I can connect to it, but when I try update or view its content but I cant see the schema button.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To find an answer to the question we suggest providing complete information on the problem. I have not used Azure myself, therefore would defer to experts in the forum to answer the question. Meanwhile, I found a related YouTube video that may help (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjNvhzBp8EA).